# React Native - global boolean isnt updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, global

Alright, Ive read similar questions here but am not understanding why my dynamic, global variable is showing 2 different values across 2 files/is not updating.

I have a global boolean I declare in File 1 like this, above the component exported in this file. I dont export this global variable:

```
global.isinLongPress = false;

class FloatingMenu extends React.PureComponent {

//this component
```

Throughout this File 1, I change the value of this boolean depending on whether a `TouchableOpacity` has been tapped. I do this here, and the boolean reads `true`:

```
handleLongMenuPress = () => {
      const { isOpen, onMenuToggle } = this.props;

      onMenuToggle(true);
      global.isinLongPress = true;

      console.log('long menu press ', global.isinLongPress);
  };
```

In File 2, I want to access this variable. This gets printed AFTER the previous console.log, however it reads the boolean as `false`:

```
console.log(global.isinLongPress);
```

What is going on here? How can I constantly get the updated value of this global variable?

Comment: you need redux, react context or something similar to be able to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Updating any non-state variable will not cause your components to re-render and have access to the latest value, they'll show the value that was set when they last rendered. Can you imagine if your whole app re-rendered when updating any single variable?

To achieve this behaviour, you can use the React `Context` API which is a simple solution to global state, more alternatives include Zustand, Jotai, MobX, Redux, etc.